# Send a Base64/BLOB image data from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to send a directly usable base64/BLOB image data to javascript?

I'm trying to send an array(containing string & img) to my Vue component from my **page.blade.php** returned from my controller in Laravel.

**MORE DETAILS**

I know data encoding is my problem and `json_encode($my_string_data)` only works for UTF-8 but not the IMG data. `json_encode($my_image_data)` will throw an error `malformed utf-8 characters possibly incorrectly encoded image`.

I am making 1 request then 2 DB queries in my controller and combining both responses(string & MEDIUMBLOB/img data) then return it as an array to my **blade.php**, in my blade file is the vue component taking in the img data as props.

Possible solutions I wanna know how:

1. How do I do make this img data directly usable by javascript?
2. If **#1** is not possible, how do I convert this img data directly readable by javascript?
3. If **#2** is not possible, how do I convert this img data JSON-able by
   `json_encode($my_image_data)` ?

[image]

I'm only assuming that the IMG data returned by the database from a BLOB column is Base64, `mb_detect_encoding()`-ing the variable containing IMG data always returns false so I cannot know what is it in the first place. All I know Is must convert this data to UTF-8 or anything JSON-able for JS to use.

ATM, I'm still trying to make solution #3.

Comment: I had the same issue before a few days ago. I used base64encode and decode.

Comment: so you decoded the IMG DATA on the way out to display right?

Comment: As per your way. with PHP you can do  base64encode on blob text. then use json_encode on it. then using javascript you can use `atob` to decode base64encoded string and get blog text again. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $image = 'yourimage'; 

// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding  
$imageData=base64_encode(file_get_contents($image)); 

// Format the image SRC: data:{mime};base64,{data}; 
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;
```

And now the src is urldata and can be ready to be transformed to js.

Comment: I was able to pass the **'data:image/png;base64,'.$base64_img_data** as props and as a string ready to be used by <img src="skill"> inside a vue template. When I try to read the props using console.log, it is **undefined** BUT I can see the string in the Chrome Vue extension debugger. 
I can actually see **"data:image/png;base64,the_garbled_base64_encoded_image..."**

Comment: I can now see the base64 image data and can even console.log as string, but then i use string (**'data:image/png;base64,218j9c8wh1...**) in <img src="skill", it's not displaying but i can see an image icon, it's just that the image is not displayed.

Comment: function getDataURI($image, $mime = '') {  return 'data: '.(function_exists('mime_content_type') ? mime_content_type($image) : $mime).';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($image)); }

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/data-uri-php  this link is the reference and you could understand better how to make it exactly.

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks!